# Formulation of regex to match js libraries and version

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to formulate how to write one regex to match this:

- I would like to write a regex to match on words like: `backbone`,`jquery`,`bootstrap`,`yui` and match on javascript library versions like 0.5.0 or 1.8 (as shown).

How can I reasonably do this with python 3?

Comment: I think you pasted incomplete text

Comment: First you can try to read that : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

And your regex could be something like that : `.*(backbone|jquery|bootstrap|yui).*/(\S+\.js).*`

Comment: Thanks @PhxDev - yeah this matches the library, but not a version e.g. `1.6.3` or `1.0rc2` - any thoughts with that

Comment: provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a starting point: use two expressions, one for the version, one for the lib:

```
import re

urls = """https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.0/backbone-min.js
https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone-0.5.0.js
https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/jquery-min.js
https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/jquery-1.6.3.js
https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.0/backbone-min.js
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.2/js/jquery.validate.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js">
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"""
rx_version = re.compile(r'[-/](\d+[.\w]*)[/.]')
rx_lib = re.compile(r'/([a-z]+)[^/]+$')
for url in urls.split("\n"):
    version, lib = None, None

    # version
    m = rx_version.search(url)
    if m:
        version = m.group(1)

    m = rx_lib.search(url)
    if m:
        lib = m.group(1)

    print(lib, version)
```

This yields

```
backbone 0.5.0
backbone 0.5.0
jquery None
jquery 1.6.3
backbone 0.5.0
jquery 4.0.2
jquery 1.0rc2
jquery 1.9.2
jquery 1.8
yui 3.5.0
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to match the `jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js`? Thoughts? Thanks again for all the support